# How can I compare a DatePicker date to the Calendar Date

Tags: android, date, calendar, format

A simple question I hope.
How can I compare the date entered into a DatePicker to the current Calendar date?

To explain, If I have the DatePicker date stored as a string, how could I compare that to the current date on the android system calendar?

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.dpresult);

textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

public void onClick(View v){         

   Intent intent = new Intent(datePickerResult.this, calander.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
});

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

year = extras.getInt("year"); 
day = extras.getInt("day"); 
month = extras.getInt("month");

textView1.setText(day+"");
```

}
}

Comment: What is your date picker date looks like? Can you give it?

Comment: Are you using the standard DatePicker widget? That handler returns 3 ints, why convert that to a String?

Answer (score 3):

for example you got the date like string from datepicker then

```
String sDate = "05-10-2012"; // suppose you create this type of date as string then

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

Date date = sdf.parse(sDate);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

c.getTime().compareTo(date);
```

it depending on your string or how you can get? you can get all individually from datepicker then directly set in calendar instance

```
Calendar my = Calendar.getInstance();
my.set(year, month, day);
```

now compare

```
my.compareTo(Calendar.getInstance());
```

Comment: @patrik, thanks, You say I can compare them directly from the datepicker so for example, if I have got the dates from the date picker as: getday, getmonth, getyear etc then how would I compare them?

Comment: ok will post quick example now for getting the datepicker results, changed from the string to standard ints, so basically just need to compare those with the calendar, thanks

Comment: I have posted some code can you give me an example of using the datepicker values directly? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your String to Date see [this](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml)

and try this  [compareTo](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29)

```
date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Comment: OP said that `If I have the DatePicker date stored as a string`

Answer (score 0):

read through a tutorial on dates here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

and this post on SO for a similar case: [How to match or compare a date string with the date stored in sqlite in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11009662/how-to-match-or-compare-a-date-string-with-the-date-stored-in-sqlite-in-android)

If none of this helps then post some code and i'll edit my answer :)